# How can I redirect to html page?

Tags: java, jquery, spring-boot

I use AJAX and REST.

`index.html` :

`<button><a href="???" class="click-me" target="_blank" type="button">Teachers</a></button>`

After click on the button `Teachers` I want to redirect to another html page - in the folder `templates/teachersViews/teachersPage.html` :

```
<script src="/teachers.js"></script>
<table id="table-content" class="table table-dark" border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
    <th>Teacher ID</th>
    <th>Teacher Name</th>
    <th>Teacher Position</th>
</tr>
```

`teachers.js` :

```
var service = 'http://localhost:8081/';
$(document).ready(function(){

jQuery.support.cors = true;

$.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        url: service + 'teachers/',
        // data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {

            var trHTML = '';

            $.each(data, function (i, teacher) {

                trHTML += '<tr><td>' + teacher.teacherId + '</td><td>' + teacher.teacherName + '</td><td>' + teacher.position + '</td></tr>';
            });

            $('#table-content').append(trHTML);
        },

        error: function (msg) {

            alert(msg.responseText);
        }
    });
})
```

And `TeacherRestController` which gets data from database - `Teacher` models :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/teachers")
public class TeacherRestController {

private static final String TEACHER_MODEL = "teacher";

@Autowired
TeacherService teacherService;

@GetMapping("")
public List<Teacher> getAllTeachers() {
    return teacherService.getAll();
}
```

To sum up, I want to click on the button `Teachers` on the page `index.html` and be redirected to the file `templates/teachersViews/teachersPage.html` where I have already with help of REST got data ( `Teacher` models from database ) .

Comment: as you defined route "/teachers" in controller you should be fine using `<a href="/teachers" ` ?

Comment: @johnSmith With route "/teachers" I get teachers on the empty page, it is not redirect to the necessary page - templates/teachersViews/teachersPage.html

Comment: did you try linking to absolute link with starting `/` e.g `href="/templates/teachersViews/teachersPage.html"` ?

Comment: @johnSmith Sure, but also has a problem :

`Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sat Jan 16 19:03:46 EET 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available`

It doesn't find this route

Comment: i dont know spring boot, but a small look at the docs https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/ shows the you need to add a name property so it automagically takes the correct view